# How to avoid explicit import of context in context consuming components for reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I just start to work with [contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in Reactjs. Lets say we have some parent component `<ContextFoo>` and somewhere down in the tree a component `<ContextConsumer>`:

```
<ContextFoo>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ContextConsumer/>
  </div>
</ContextFoo>
```

My expectation was that if I exchange `<ContextFoo>` with another component `<ContextBaa>`,
the `<ContextConsumer/>` would automatically use the new context. This strategy would provide me some
[inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

However, it seems that `<ContextConsumer/>` needs to depend on a specific context.

The applied context does not seem to be defined by

a) the dom structure (going up the tree and looking for the nearest context provider) <= my expectation

but by

b) using some explicitly imported context in the class for the consumer:

```
import {ExplicitContext} from '../ContextFoo;

class ContextConsumer extends React.Component {
  static contextType = ExplicitContext;
  render() {
    let value = this.context;
    /* render something based on the value */
  }
}
```

=> How can I avoid that explicit import/dependency in the ContextConsumer?

```
class ContextConsumer extends React.Component {      
  render() {
    let value = this.automatic_dom_context;
    /* render something based on the value */
  }
}
```

Comment: You must import the context... Thats the API. If you want something generic do it on the provider/consumer implementation

Comment: To be clear, there is no built-in option to look for the nearest context.